# Fading out a shape. I have to use factory pattern to make Shapes Circle and rect

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas, ondraw, fading

I have to use factory pattern to make Shapes Circle and rect . SO i made a button that called rect and circ and when i click it makes a circle or rect, but the issue is that I have to make it fading out everything i make a new circle the old one is to fade with each new one made out until its completely invisibly and popped off but i dont know how to do it or start. I was told to traverse vector and subtract alpha of them android. "As new shapes are
added, the previously drawn shapes fade away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think I understand you're issue, correct me if I don't.

From what it sounds like, you might want to add an animation listener to your animation.  The docs can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)

Specifically, you'll want to look at the onAnimationEnd callback.  You can use that to start a new animation/create new shape/do whatever once a fade-out animation is complete